# How can I enable folder sharing in Google Docs? Can I write my own program/application for it?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, gmail, google-docs

Google Docs does provide sharing of files.But it does not provide sharing of folders.

Is there any way by which I can share the folders too? Can I write my own application/program for it?

If yes, then how?

> **UPDATE:** Now this question is no longer
>   useful.Gmail now supports folder
>   sharing too.Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to start is to go through the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/overview.html). I would also recommend you check out [this videocast](http://www.zendcasts.com/introduction-to-the-google-docs-api/2009/08/) (it shows how to do this in PHP, but you should be able to replicate this to any other language you might be using). Good luck.

Comment: It(documentation) seems interesting.But I couldn't figure out what language is that.How can I actually implement it?

Comment: Check out the sample code http://code.google.com/apis/documents/code.html (btw in which language are you trying to do this?).

Answer (score 0):

I found a discussion at google (support forum, I'd link if I could have more than one/post)

Down the page there is a link to an app that supposedly uses new API features to implement folder sharing
http://tng.appspot.com/2009/9/Folder-Sharing-in-Google-Docs-now-possible

Answer (score 0):

After reading my blog post mentioned by goorj you can try out my folder sharing app at

[http://folders.gdoclab.com](http://folders.gdoclab.com/)

You will be asked to login using you google account and give permission to manipulate you google docs sharing permission. It works for plain google accounts not for google apps accounts yet (but I am working on that too ...)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can write your own application using Google docs APIs.